# Visual Studio 2012 creating an empty class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Why when i create an empty c++ class in Visual studio 2012 it appears a download of a default.htm and not the normal interface?

[image]

Comment: You've got to be *much* more descriptive than that.

Comment: i.e. explain how you are creating a new class, what step causes the download to pop up, what you 'expect' to see and why.

Comment: It's possible that even an empty class contains a non-trivial constructor that performs a network operation. You should probably use a singleton or a factory to avoid such side effects.

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623875/visual-studio-2012-c-creating-a-class)  especially a duplicate of your own post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is connected, but Visual Studio has an implicit dependency on Internet Explorer.  Make sure IE is installed and working - you can get strange effects in Visual Studio if IE is not up to date.

Comment: IE was not updated, now it perfectly works ! Thanks.

Comment: It took me ages to figure this one out when it happened to me in a slightly different scenario.  Please upvote if you agree with the answer.